# Can I view the Markdown-source of an unedited question/answer?

Tags: support, edits

Once a post has been edited, you can go into the revision list, and click "View Source".

If a post has not been edited (and I don't have the edit privilege) is there any way to see the raw Markdown?

The reason I ask I because of ["Preview should match the posted view"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view/1246#1246) - it's impossible to see the source markdown, and how it's different from the rendered Markdown.

Not exactly a huge issue, just curious!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's possible, but it's not exposed in the UI. What you need to do is isolate the post number (I'm using this post, 1690, as an example) and go to this url:

[`https://sitename.stackexchange.com/posts/{post-id}/revisions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1690/revisions)

From here, you can click the "view source" button to see the source of the post.

Comment: Hacker              ;)

Comment: Wow! Backdoors to the system! You are the keymaker in the matrix!

Comment: You should use `1691` as the example id ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy 'n paste URLs anymore: you can simply click `edit` below the question/answer. This gives you access to the Markdown source.

Depending on the Stack website you are in, you can have `improve this answer/question` instead of `edit`.

Note that this solution might be not available depending on your reputation level.

Comment: It doesn't work if someone else has suggested a pending edit.