# ASCII-art formatting in SO?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

Can someone tell me how [Dictionary<T> of List<T> and ListViews in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583689/dictionaryt-of-listt-and-listviews-in-asp-net) was formatted?

I know how to do this in a text editor, but I can't figure out how it is done on the Stack Overflow question form. It works here if I format it as code, but not on Stack Overflow.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|           Name Of Item          |  DropDownList (of List<T>)   |
|---------------------------------|  _____________________       |
|                foo1             |  |     bar1      | v |       |
|                                 |  |_______________|___|       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                 |  DropDownList (of List<T>)   |
|                                 |  _____________________       |
|                foo2             |  |     bar2      | v |       |
|                                 |  |_______________|___|       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Interesting presentation to explain your point.

Comment: Looks like you didn't have any trouble replicating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author of that question just put his "drawing" in `<pre>` tags. But code formatting (i.e. 4-space-indent) should work, too---on SO as well.

But since that would leave you with syntax-highlighted drawings, it might not be desirable anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I'm suddenly reminded of the DOS (and before) days of looking for the right border glyphs for the single/double border lines... sadly they don't seem to translate to most common modern type faces, but them were the days ;-p

Comment: Yay! My first attempt at writing a drawing program was text mode and used those lines. Good ol' COMAL days... Thanks Marc, now you've got me thinking of better times for the rest of the day...

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly using an ascii art generator, such as [asciio](http://perlbuzz.com/2008/04/asciio-lets-you-create-ascii-charts-graphically.html).

I downloaded it from the Fedora repositories, and when I create a diagram in it and then right click on the background, I can save the diagram to a text file.  From there I just need to copy the text, and paste into a <pre> block.

Comment: The problem is how to get it to display on StackOverflow, not how to generate the text.

Comment: That was not created with asciio, the corners are different.

Answer (score 1):

The question in the link that you posted has been edited at least once.

You can click the "Edited X hours ago" link. This will bring up an interface containing the revision history. Find the appropriate version and click the "view source" link. This way you can see exactly what the author typed when he asked the question.

This method is useful whenever you see some kind of of formatting that you'd wish to know how the author achieved.

If the post has not been edited, you can use  [this method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/can-i-view-the-markdown-source-of-an-unedited-question-answer/1691#1691) to access the revision history.