# Changing to Community Wiki seems to have lost history

Tags: support, status-bydesign, revisions-list

If you look at [What made you change your long-living opinion regarding some aspect of programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426546/what-made-you-change-your-long-living-opinion-regarding-some-aspect-of-programmin) you'll see theres no history. This was a non-CW question that was changed to CW. Also, it has been closed and reopened (confirmed by the 10k+ tools as having received 5 close votes but it's open with no close votes).

Did changing it to CW either scupper the close process or just lose the history?

Answer (score 3):

It has 5 re-open votes:
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1426546/list

Comment: Theres no link to that URL that I see so that would be the bug or am I missing that URL from the page somewhere?

Comment: As long as the post hasn't been edited yet, the link does not exist. You have to construct it yourself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/can-i-view-the-markdown-source-of-an-unedited-question-answer/1691#1691

Answer (score 1):

No edits == no history.