# How do I get Markdown source code during a pending edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits

When trying to answer a badly formatted question, I tend to click "edit" to view the raw Markdown text, as this tends to be better formatted than the displayed text.

But during a *pending suggested edit*, I can't view this, so I can't see, for example on Stack Overflow, the correct format of the data layout.

Is there a way around this?

The following image illustrates this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I view the Markdown-source of an unedited question/answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/can-i-view-the-markdown-source-of-an-unedited-question-answer) (the accepted answer shows how)

Comment: If your request is different from what already exists, [edit] your question and explain what you are looking for, such as a better workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a mechanism already exists. From [Kyle Cronin's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1691/388442) to [Can I view the Markdown-source of an unedited question/answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1690/388442):

> It's possible, but it's not exposed in the UI. What you need to do is isolate the post number (I'm using this post, 1690, as an example) and go to this url:
>
> [`https://sitename.stackexchange.com/posts/{post-id}/revisions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1690/revisions)
>
> From here, you can click the "view source" button to see the source of the post.

On this question, the revisions URL would be https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/329248/revisons.

Also, if the question has been previously edited, clicking the *edited x mins ago* link goes to the revisions page.